# Check if sequential list of incrementing numbers misses any number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`Category` has many `Post`.

All posts in a category have a `position` attribute, starting with number 1 and the last number should be the total post count for that category.

How do I most efficiently check that the incrementing list of position numbers doesn't have any duplicates or lapses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
array = @posts.pluck(:position)
array.sort.each_cons(2).all? { |x,y| y == x + 1 }
```

Returns `false`, if they are not incrementing in equal steps or contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably offload that kind of work to the [`acts as list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem, it will do what you're after with pretty minimal fuss.

As for getting the 'total post count', don't rely on a position, ask your database! `@category.posts.count`